# Trying to sum part of the rows

Tags: sql, sum

So I have three tables
Orders:

```
CustomerID,OrderID
```

Order Details;

```
OrderID,ProductId,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount
```

And Products:

```
ProductID,ProductName
```

And I need to combine these 2 tables and create this one:

```
[Orderd Details].CustomersID,Products.ProductName,FORMULA
```

Formula is how much money people spent money on this product. So I think I have to sum UnitPrice* Quantity*(1-Discount) from every order for this product.
Sadly I have no idea how should I do it. The best I did is:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID,p.ProductName,SUM(od.Quantity*od.UnitPrice*(1-od.Discount)) as 'SKZ' 
FROM Customers as c, Orders as o,[Order Details] as od,Products as p 
WHERE (o.OrderID=od.OrderID AND p.ProductID=od.ProductID) 
GROUP BY od.ProductID ORDER BY o.CustomerID;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is almost always a bad error description. What exactly doesn't work and what is the expected output? Show an example.

Answer (score 1):

First, learn explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Second, you should include all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, p.ProductName,
       SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1 - od.Discount)) as SKZ
FROM Orders as o JOIN
     [Order Details] od 
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID JOIN
     Products p 
     ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
GROUP BY o.CustomerID, p.ProductName
ORDER BY o.CustomerID;
```

Comment: <ul>
<li>1.Thank you for such quick answer that helped me a lot.</li>
<li>2.I am really really really new to SQL so I really really thank you for some advices u gave me besides solving my problem.</li>
3.I have one question is '[Order Details] as od' is the same as '[Order Details] od' ?I think u are missing some '(' or there is one not needed ')'.
Can I change formatting of 'skz' ?

Comment: **3.** Yes  **4.** Was an extra `)` **5.** Depend on your db there are string function to format numbers

Comment: Thank you again ,when I was making a post I didnt even know that I could use GROUP BY column1,column2 .  In this case I will try to use Round() function.